# Interface is not in a column

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, layout

i am currently coding a produkt system and I am designing the interface. My Problem is, that the Interface is not in a colume. [image] I want it in one colume with my code code, also it would be good to add one more Button in the row of "suche nach waren"
Here is the code:

```
GroupLayout tLayout = new GroupLayout(mainFrame.getContentPane());
mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(tLayout);
tLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
tLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

tLayout.setHorizontalGroup(tLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel0))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel1)
                .addComponent(tLabel2)
                .addComponent(tLabel3)
                .addComponent(tLabel4))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tTextField1)
                .addComponent(tTextField2)
                .addComponent(tTextField3)
                .addComponent(tCombo)
                .addComponent(tButton1))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tTable))
        );

tLayout.setVerticalGroup(tLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(tLabel0)
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel1)
                .addComponent(tTextField1))
            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel2)
                .addComponent(tTextField2))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel3)
                .addComponent(tTextField3))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tLabel4)
                .addComponent(tCombo))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tButton1))
        .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(tTable)));
```

Whats wrong with my code?
I appreciate your answer!

PS.: I do not want to use a layout editor because its my first time and I want to learn about SWING!

PPS.:

```
|Geben sie bitte die Kriterien für die Suche an:  
|Name:            (textfield)  
|Maximaler Preis: (textfield)  
|Alter des Kunden:(textfield)  
|Kategorie:       (Combo)  
|                 (Button)  
|Table....
```

Everything is in the right place except the upper label and the table

Comment: "_I appreciate your answer_" Then please add a real question.

Comment: Draw in ASCII art how the controls are supposed to be arranged at minimum size and when extra space/height is given to the container.  +1 for adding a question.

Comment: Suggestion: if you want to hand code a layout, stay away from the `GroupLayout`. As said in the tutorial, that layout was designed to be used by GUI builder tools and suited for hand coding (it is doable, but it is a PITA)

Comment: btw ascii art is extremely hard...

Comment: For such a form-like layout I always recommend the `FormLayout` of JGoodies, but that is a 3th party lib

Comment: is there an option to create that in SWING?

Comment: FormLayout is Swing layout manager, but you could also do the same thing using GridBagLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridBagLayout Example...

[image]

You really should put the `JTable` inside a JScrollPane, it will take care of the header for you, but hay

```
public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new FormPane());
                frame.setSize(600, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected static class FormPane extends JPanel {

        public FormPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            add(new JLabel("Geben sie bitte die Kriterien für die Suche an:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Maximaler Preis:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Alter des Kunden:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Kategorie:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JComboBox(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JButton("Click me"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                            new Object[][] {
                                {"id", "Name", "Price", "Something", "Something", "Something"},
                                {"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"}
                            },
                            new Object[]{"id", "Name", "Price", "Something", "Something", "Something"});


            add(new JTable(model), gbc);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time I see such a code snippet and the result I say to myself I should spend some time learning the `GridBagLayout`, but one look at that code makes me run back to the `FormLayout`. Could you also explain why on earth your `FormPane` extends from `JLabel`. An extension was not even needed, but if you use it, why not from `JPanel` ?

Comment: Hahhaha, I was wondering why I was having issues displaying it, copied from an old example

Comment: @robin I have the same feelings about FormLayout. I really want to learn it and I think it would solve a number of problems that good old GridBagLayout can't, but I look at the code and it makes my head spin. Spent 3 years hand coding layouts with GridBagLayout, you get kinda use to it